# Importing API Values from one JS into another NODEjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

so I am trying to import API data from one JS file into another but I keep getting undefined or just errors. The variables I am trying to import are Weather, City and Temperature from the weathermap.js into the app.js. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Is it to do with how I'm exporting from weathermap.js or how I'm importing into app.js??

---

### app.js

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const hbs = require('hbs');
const myForecast = require('./weathermap');
var appweather = myForecast.weather;
var appcity = myForecast.city;
var apptemperature = myForecast.temperature;


// This actually makes express run in our file
const app = express();
const publicDirectory = path.join(__dirname, "../public");
const viewsPath = path.join(__dirname, '../templates/views');
const partialPath = path.join(__dirname, '../templates/partials');
hbs.registerPartials(partialPath);


// console.log("This is the variable info: ", weather, city, temperature)
myForecast("Manchester", "uk", "metric");



app.use(express.static(publicDirectory));

app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
app.set('views', viewsPath);

// var weather = require('./weathermap.js').weather;
// var city = require('./weathermap.js').city;
// var temperature = require('./weathermap.js').temperature;

app.get("/", (req, res) => {    
    // console.log(myForecast.city);
    res.render("index", {
        title: 'Weather App',
        author: 'Frazer MacRostie',
        city: appcity,
        weather: appweather,
        temperature: apptemperature
    });
});

// app.get("")

app.get("/about", (req, res) => {    
    res.render("about", {
    });
});

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.send('<h1>404 your page does not exist</h1>')
})

// console.log(__dirname);
// console.log(__filename);

app.listen(3000, ()=>{
    console.log(myForecast.city);
    console.log("Server is running on localhost 3000");
})
```

---

### weathermap.js

```
const request = require('request');
var weather = "";
var city = "";
var temperature = "";


const forecast = (city, country, units) => {

    const encodedCityName = encodeURIComponent(city);
    const encodedCountryName = encodeURIComponent(country);

    const weatherMapUrl = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${encodedCityName},${encodedCountryName}&units=${units}&APPID=4fe147c8dc2f848fd447182ebd444e80`

    request({ url: weatherMapUrl, json: true }, (error, response) => {
        // console.log(response.body);

        weather = `${response.body.weather[0].main}`
        city = `${response.body.name}`
        temperature = `${response.body.main.temp}`
        console.log(weather, city, temperature)

        if(error) {
            console.log("ERROR! Cannot connect to the API services.")
        } else if (city === undefined){
            console.log("I'm sorry, that City does not exist.")
        } else{
            console.log(`Today we have mainly ${weather}`)

            console.log(`The current temperature in ${city} is ${temperature}°C`)
        }
        return weather + city + temperature;


    })
}

// module.exports = weather;
// module.exports = city;
// module.exports = temperature;
module.exports = forecast;

// exports.forecast = () => {
//     return weather + city + temperature;
//   };


// &units=metric
// &units=imperial
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting undefined because you are calling the async API in the weathermap.js file. Which will wait for the request to complete. So use the **async/await or Promise** .then callback to wait for the api to complete the call.

Answer (score 0):

Before your weathermap response data return function call and return, that why getting undefined.
you can set **async or promise** in your function.